# Passing parameters to Controller on click of a button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This might be a trivial question, me being a new bee :)
Here is my View code

```
<button type="button" id="btnLogin" onclick="location.href='<%: Url.Action("Authenticate", "Login") %>'" runat="server"></button>
```

Here is my Controller code

```
 public ActionResult Authenticate(string username,string password)
    {
        bool status = Login.Authenticate(username, password);
        return View("Status", status);
    }
```

I'm able to go to that controller but i'm unable to pass the parameters.Can any let me know what is the rite way to pass parameters to controller function.

***Full View Code***

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtUsername" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtPassword" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <button type="button" id="btnLogin" onclick="location.href='<%: Url.Action("Authenticate", "Login") %>'" runat="server"></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you please copy the full html form in your question?

Comment: @Gabriel updated plz have a look

Comment: With the current answers you're getting there. One thing I wanted to add is that you need the input fields names to match your parameter names in the controller if you want ASP.NET MVC to bind the values. ie  `<input type="text" id="username" name="username" />` will match with `string username`

Answer (score 3):

You can pass input values with its `name` attribute.

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm("Authenticate", "Login"))
{%>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txtUsername" name="username" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txtPassword" name="password"  />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="submit_button"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<%}%>
```

CONTROLLER

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Authenticate(string username, string password)
{
    bool status = Login.Authenticate(username, password);
    return View("Status", status);
}
```

Comment: If you want to do it with any button (not submit, and no form), you can use ajax post.

Comment: its still giving me null parameters

Comment: Are your view name and action name same? If they are different, write action url to BeginForm like this: `Html.BeginForm("Authenticate", "Login")` and add HttpPost attribute to action

Comment: Also, model using is the better.Purpose of MVC architecture is using models between controllers and views

Comment: ys they are both same Authenticate.But still getting null parameters,I checked putting a break point in the controller action

Comment: @iJade I am also facing the same issue ..did you able to resolve ?

Answer (score 3):

you know there is a third parameter to url action where you can add parameter

```
@Url.Action("Authenticate", "Login" , new {name = "name"})
```

you just need a way to add your value there

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<form>` that posts to the Authenticate method in your controller. Also change the `<button>` to a `<input type="submit"`

Like this:

```
<form method="post" action="@Href("~/account/authenticate")" id="LogOnForm">
.... @*input boxes*@
<input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

EDIT: for ajax login, use this script (jquery is required). Note that the form needs an `ID`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#LogOnForm").submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();                
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Content("~/account/authenticate")',
                    data: $("#LogOnForm").serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {                       
                       if (data.Status) {
                            //Logged in succesfully
                         } else {
                            //Login failed
                         }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {                            
                        console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
      });

    </script>
```

EDIT: Controller Modification:

```
public JsonResult Authenticate(string username,string password)
    {
        bool status = Login.Authenticate(username, password);
        return Json( new @"Status", status);
    }
```

Comment: well i dont want to post the form...is there any way to do it my way

Comment: then change the `method="post"` to `method="get"` or you can use Ajax

Comment: how to do it using AJAX.any useful links

Comment: you will need two things for an ajax login. Firstly, use jquery to perform the ajax query (more here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and secondly, your `Authenticate` method needs to return a `JsonResult` instead of an ActionResult.

Answer (score 0):

You need to at the parameters into the call string using Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function postdata(location) {
        var url = '<%: Url.Action("Authenticate", "Login", new { username = XXX, password = YYY) %>';
        var Username = document.getElementById(Username).value;
        var Password= document.getElementById(Password).value;
        url = url.replace("XXX", Username );
        url = url.replace("YYY", Password);
        location.href=url;
    }
</script>

<button type="button" id="btnLogin" onclick="postdata()" runat="server"></button>
```

Comment: You don't 'need' to do that using javascript, it's an option.

Comment: i am still getting null parameters.Checked putting a break point in the controller action

Comment: Fair comment.  'Need' may be the wrong word, but I find it the most effective method.

Answer (score 0):

Missing name property on your input fields. Add a name property to your username and password input boxes. The name property should be same as your action controller arguments.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtUsername" runat="server" name="username" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtPassword" runat="server"  name="password"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <button type="button" id="btnLogin" onclick="location.href='<%: Url.Action("Authenticate", "Login") %>'" runat="server"></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```