# Passing form values from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am newbie to ASP.NET MVC and I have view which consist of some form values and there are 2 buttons save and cancel. On button save click, I want to send the form values to controller method.

When I searched I found input button type submit but I want to save the values in database without post. Is it possible without doing post?

test.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Cars";
}
<style>
    .form-group {
        margin-bottom: 0rem;
    }
</style>
<div class="modal test" id="testModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="testModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-test dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Car</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="forms-sample">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">CarName</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtName" placeholder="car Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Car Type</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="drpcarTypes">
                                <option value="0"> --Select--</option>
                                <option value="1"> Petrol</option>
                                <option value="2"> Diesel</option>
                                <option value="3"> Hybrid</option>
                                <option value="5"> EV</option>

                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Email Id</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="emaiId" rows="4"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-gradient-ghsd-dark" data-bs-dismiss="modal" style="padding: 0.55rem 1.12rem;">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-gradient-sdjuk-primary" style="padding: 0.55rem 1.2rem;">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: found same post but there are no working answers.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822114/passing-parameters-to-controller-on-click-of-a-button